# Xamarin Forms Error => "jarsigner.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting **"jarsigner.exe" exited with code 1** and I have to **change the keystore location** for which I don't know how to change in xamarin form in Windows bcoz I copied this project from MAC to Windows and I had a problem in PROGUARD as java.exe exited with error code 1 so I disabled PROGUARD and now **jarsigner.exe error**

```
1>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "/Users/ekambaram/Desktop/CYBER/App Store - Cyb/Cyber Certifcate/my-release-key.keystore" -storepass 098765 -keypass 098765 -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\com.Cyber.Cyber-Signed-Unaligned.apk E:\CyberPortable\CyberPortable\CyberPortable.Droid\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.Cyber.Cyber.apk Cyber
1>"jarsigner.exe" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "CyberPortable.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please add a diagnostic build output: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: Secondly, you can take that exact line and execute it on the command line. It should spit out a better error. There's a similar bug reported here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56838

Comment: Finally, double check all of your paths. The keystore path looks mac specific rather than a Windows path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0) Open your Android project Options

1) Select Android Package Signing

2) Select configuration, that your trying to build

3) Check "Sign the .APK ..."

4) Select **my-release-key.keystore** file on your windows machine, you can copy it from your mac

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find that **Android project Options** , I tried checking on right-clicking the Droid or Android Project also which doesn't contain such option but i'll try checking it again and let you know, thanks mate.

Comment: Right Click on the projectname.droid there will be options