# jarsigner.exe exited with code 1 when trying to deploy a signed apk in android device- Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin Android application. I am able to build the Droid project successfully and when I try to sign the application in release mode  the .apk is also created but is not getting deployed in my Android device. I am getting the error message as

```
"jarsigner.exe" exited with code 1.
Done building project "XXX.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
Deploy failed on Google Pixel 2
```

Where as I am able to run the normal application without any keystore signing.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Note: It is Xamarin.Forms - android application

Comment: Enable msbuild verbosity to diagnostic level and obtain the full error message.

Comment: You could refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158257/xamarin-forms-error-jarsigner-exe-exited-with-code-1